# Gradient function of a circle

Tags: calculus, derivatives, circles, parametric

The parametric equations of a circle $C$ are:
\begin{align*}
x&=2+\dfrac{13}{5\sqrt{2}}\cos t\\
y&=1+\dfrac{13}{5\sqrt{2}}\sin t
\end{align*}
for $t\in[0,2\pi]$.

I am stuck on this part: Find the gradient function of the circle $C$, leaving it in terms of the parameter $t$.

Comment: Do you know what is the definition of the gradient?

Comment: where exactly are you stuck on? This is simple application of chain rule

Comment: What do you mean by "the gradient function of the circle"?

Comment: Is it $\dfrac{dy}{dt}\dfrac{dt}{dx}=\cos t\dfrac{1}{-\sin t}=-\cot t$?

Comment: @bibo_extreme correct method, although we usually just call this the derivative with respect to t rather than the gradient.

Answer (score 1):

The implicit equation of the given circle is $F(x,y)=(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2=R^2$, $R=13/5\sqrt{2}$.
The gradient of the function $F$ is the vector field:

$$\mbox{grad}(F)=\left(\displaystyle\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}, \displaystyle\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\right)^T=(2(x-2),\: 2(y-1))^T$$

Now you have to evaluate the gradient at the circle points:

$$\mbox{grad}(F)(x(t), y(t))=\left((26/5\sqrt{2})\cos{t},\: (26/5\sqrt{2})\sin{t}\right)^T$$